# Explicar Linha de Código (You can loop through object properties by using the for-in loop)

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += myObj[x] + "<br>";
```

Comment: Está concatenando o valor de `myObj[x]` ao conteúdo do elemento de id `demo`.

Comment: Enganei-me, ja vou reestruturar a Pergunta anterior ... peço desculpa, mas Fiquei esclarecido com a sua Resposta !

Comment: Ja esta !
Não Estraga, porque a Resposta ja esta la em baixo a Pergunta Correta

Comment: @ManiacSaw faça assim, ao abrir uma pergunta, procure por o código o mais completo possível, mas além disso explique as partes que você entende e as que não, assim a gente pode concentrar a explicação na parte que realmente você está com dificuldade.

Comment: ok...Vou fazer isso, em proximas Dúvidas que tiver

Comment: E não tenha receio de perguntar, a recomendação é apenas para um melhor proveito do site. Com o tempo, vai pegando o jeito.

Comment: ... O que o título tem a ver com a pergunta?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida JavaScript ( Loopin through an array using a for loop )](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176678/d%c3%bavida-javascript-loopin-through-an-array-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você já viu na pergunta anterior,

```
 document.getElementById("demo")
```

serve para recuperar do DOM (a estrutura da página, montada conforme o HTML) um elemento definido por `id="demo"`.

Em seguida, o

```
.innerHTML
```

recupera uma referência para o HTML que está dentro deste elemento. Depois, o

```
+=
```

significa "adicione ao final" um determinado valor ( `a += b` equivale a `a = a + b` em praticamente qualquer linguagem).

O que vai ser adicionado ao elemento é isto:

```
myObj[x] + "<br>";
```

Sendo que `myObj[x]` é um *array*, ou seja, uma coleção de ítens. No caso, o ítem adicionado vai ser pego da variável `x`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado ... E peço Desculpa por estas Perguntas um Pouco "Amadoras", mas estou tentando perceber as minhas dúvidas 100% para ter umas boas Bases !

Comment: Ja estou a ler ... pensei estar a Criar mas afinal tava a Editar ... To Mutch Coffe .... Desculpe-me .... Vou tentar ser mais Claro possível no futuro .

Comment: @Bacco Sei que a sua resposta já foi aceita, mas procurando no histórico de edições da pergunta, havia mais conteúdo importante lá. Suponho que o OP tenha escolhido remover a HTML pertinente por não saber formatá-la, o que faz com que a engine do SE a elimine.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ele acabou fazendo uma pergunta separada. Ele mesmo reverteu pq eu respondi a versão anterior. Sua intenção foi boa, mas no fim esse conteúdo extra acabou ficando em outro post melhor, então voltei ao estado que se encontrava..