# Dúvida JavaScript ( Loopin through an array using a for loop )

Tags: javascript

Neste Exemplo abaixo , tenho dúvidas mais em especifico nestas linhas de Código.
Gostaria de saber em detalhado se for possível, as suas funções!

**Dúvida:**

```
for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
        x += myObj.cars[i] + "<br>";
```

**Exemplo:**

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
};

for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
    x += myObj.cars[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual sua dúvida?

Comment: Esta na descrição .

Comment: Você rodou esse código ?

Comment: Sim, mas estando a funcionar não significa que eu perceba ... Dai eu estar a questionar aquele bocado de Linha de código

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aqui é criado um parágrafo vazio em HTML, e dado um `id` a ele:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Na parte do `script`, em JavaScript é criado um objeto. Um objeto pode ter uma lista de valores, indicados por `[ ]` ou chaves e valores, indicados por `{ }`.

Um objeto pode ter outros objetos dentro. No caso do seu exemplo, `myObj` tem 3 ítens, `name`, `age` e `cars`:

```
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
};
```

Os dois primeiros tem valores, o terceiro tem uma lista de valores.

Em seguida, é feito um `loop` onde `i` começa de zero e vai incrementando, enquanto não é do tamanho do elemento `cars` (no caso, enquanto for menor que 3):

```
for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
```

O `for` é composto por 3 expressões essenciais:

```
for( expressão inicial; condição para executar; operação a executar ao fim de cada iteração)
```

No caso concreto, inicialmente `i = 0`. A condição para terminar o `for` é `i < myObj.cars.length`. A cada vez que o conteúdo das `{ }` é executado, o `i++` aumenta o valor de `i` em `1`

A expressão `i++` equivale a `i = i + 1`. De curiosidade, se em vez de `i++` fosse `i += 7` a expressão, `i` incrementaria de `7` em `7`.

Se quiséssemos o tamanho de `myObj` em vez de `cars` seria `myObj.length` em vez de `myObj.cars.length`. A propriedade `length` é a que retorna o tamanho.

No caso, este trecho será executado 3 vezes, com `i` variando de 0 a 2.

```
    x += myObj.cars[i] + "<br>";
```

A cada "volta" do loop, seria pego um dos carros, ficando este valor no `x`:

```
Ford<br>BMW<br>Fiat<br>
```

Finalmente, o valor de `x` seria posto dentro do parágrafo do começo do código:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 aqui é pego o elemento          e o conteúdo HTML dele recebe o valor de `x`
```

Comment: "No caso, este trecho será executado 3 vezes, com i variando de 0 a 3."

Só uma correção, ele vai de 0 a 2, passando por 0,1 e 2. Pois o for indica que é de 0 até menor que myObj.cars.length, que é 3.

Comment: @JonathanMachado OPS :) arrumei. Grato pelo aviso.

Comment: Obrigado... Consigo agora perceber melhor a situação... podes me so dizer o nome disto para ir procurar ( i = 0; i )

Comment: @ManiacSaw acrescentei na resposta, se eu achar algum link explicando o _loop_ `for`, adiciono depois. Um exemplo: `for( i = 7; i < 15; i += 2 ) { }` vai executar o que estiver dentro de `{ }` com os valores 7, 9, 11, e 13. Não vai executar com 15, pois a condição é < 15.

Answer (score 2):

1. Percorre a lista de items do objeto `myObj`, no índice `cars`. Quando se coloca `.length` está contando a quantidade de itens. Nesse caso são 3.
2. Lista um item de `cars` de cada vez, e pula linha.

---

```
for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
    x += myObj.cars[i] + "<br>";
}
```

```js
var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
};

for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
    x += myObj.cars[i] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

tag p com id #demo

```
var myObj, i, x = "";
```

inicialização das variáveis.

```
myObj = {
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
};
```

atribuição da variável myObj a um objeto JSON, com 3 propriedades: name, age e cars.
sendo cars um array.

```
for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
```

um loop pelo array cars.

```
x += myObj.cars[i] + "<br>";
```

concatenando na variável x o valor do carro + uma tag

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

imprimindo no HTML a string com os carros

Porém, pessoalmente eu escreveria assim:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj = {
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.cars.join('<br>');
</script>
```

E obteria o mesmo resultado.
um carro embaixo do outro, com a quebra de linha